# Converting XMLHttpRequest responseText to XML data

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, responsetext

Well, I'm trying to get RSS feed from an Website. But the response of XMLHttpRequest doesn't have any responseXML (i.e it is null). But all the rss data is in the responseText. I only want to take a part of this data.
Now I want to parse this responseTEXT to get the data I need. But querySelector doesn't work on strings.
Is there any Javascript library that'll allow me to do that?
Or some library that'll set the data of responseXML?

Pleas help. And thanks in advance. :(

Answer (score 0):

If there is no responseXML, that means that your XML is not valid. Could be malformed or you are missing a content type.

Open up the url you are fetching directly in the browser and it will normally point you to the error.

Comment: I have done that several times. But the page opens nicely.

For Example: www.bengalinux.org/cgi-bin/abhidhan/index.pl?en_word=very

Opens nicely in the webbrowser. But no responseXML in the return of XMLHttpRequest. Is it something to do with non-english language?

P.S: I'm trying to do this for a Windows App.